# Concatenate letters problems

Tags: c++

Hi basically i`m trying to make a word guessing game, everything works fine but i just can not concatenate letters, i tried everything changing types, using srtcat, append or +, in the code bellow the problem is commented out. How can i fix it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{   
time_t t;
srand((unsigned) time(&t)); 
int randNum = (rand() % 4);


string animals[5] = {   "dog",
                        "fox",
                        "wolf",
                        "cat",
                        "mouse" };

char letters_input;
char placeholder = '_';
bool wordnotfound = true;
char output;
int cnt = 0;

cin >> letters_input;

while (wordnotfound)
{
    string word = animals[4];
    for(int i=0;i<word.length();i++)
    {
        if (letters_input == word[i])
        {
            //strcat(output,word[i]);    
            //output += word[i];        
        }       
        else
        {
            //strcat(output,placeholder);
            //output += placeholder;
            cnt++;  
        }       
    }
    cout << output << endl; 
    if(cnt == 0)
    {
        wordnotfound = false;
    }
    else 
    {
        cin >> letters_input;
        cout << output << endl; 
    }       
}
system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

Comment: `output` is a `char`. A `char` can only ever hold one character's worth of data. You are therefore using the wrong type.

Answer (score 1):

The major problem is that you try to concatenate to a *single character*.

Instead make the string a proper `std::string`, then you can use the `+=` expression.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is this:

```
char (=output) + string (=word)
```

This doesn’t work because you’re trying to add  a `string` to a `char`, but a `char` can only hold one character. Instead, you need to convert the output `char*` to a `std::string`. You can do that as follows:

```
std::string(output) + word;
```

The easiest way to do this in your code however, is simply changing the type of `char output` to `std::string output`, and then you can do `output + word` whereever you like.